# Mysql Insert with milisecond

Tags: mysql

We're building chat system for our project. When user create chat group or send message to a group, we have to take user event time with milisecond. The sample database is below.

```
CREATE TABLE `chats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `chat_id` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `chat_user` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_type` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'users',
  `last_seen` datetime(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `delete_date` datetime(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `update_date` datetime(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `create_date` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The problem is, when we insert new data into table, mysql takes current time as "0000-00-00 00:00:00.000". All zero, not even date. But if we edit that data after insert, current_timestamp works perfect.

Comment: Why do you need such precision?

Comment: Just tried an insert on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b3d37/1) and it works fine.

Comment: We deleted NO_ZERO_IN_DATE module. Could it be related to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> When inserting a new row, the default value for a column with an expression default can be inserted either by omitting the column name or by specifying the column as DEFAULT (just as for columns with literal defaults):

So, your options here for getting the default value to kick in are either doing an insert which does not mention the column at all, or using the placeholder `DEFAULT`.  Both of the following should generate the same result:

```
INSERT INTO chats (id, chat_id, status, chat_user, user_type, last_seen, delete_date,
    update_date, create_date)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1.0, 'tim', 'admin', DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO chats (id, chat_id, status, chat_user, user_type)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1.0, 'tim', 'admin');
```

Answer (score 0):

$timestamp=round(microtime(true) * 1000);
store $timestamp variable value in your database column. This is utc based timestamp and you can easily convert it into local time as well.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that OP mentioned anything about using PHP

Comment: This may be the solution to the problem, but I am looking for a smoother solution. It would be much better if I could handle this problem in the process of adding data to the database.